# the method does not display as supposed in method

Tags: java, class

I created a class like this

```
public Move(char colour, int number) //a constructor takes 2 input
{
    this.colour = colour;            
    this.number = number;            
}

public static int convertColourtoNum(char colour)    
{
    int index = 0;
    if (colour == 'R')
        index = '0';
    else if (colour == 'Y')
        index = '1';
    else if (colour == 'G')
        index = '2';
    else 
        index = '3';
    return index;   //return the colour in type int after being converted

}
```

then in other class I use this method to display

```
Move m = new Move('R', 4);
    System.out.println("Display "  + m.convertColourtoNum(m.getColour()));
```

The problem is the code is supposed to display

> Display 0

but instead, it displays

> Display 48

Why does it happen? Thank you

Comment: You're assigning a `char` instead of `int`. Change `'0'` to `0` etc.

Comment: Because the character I entered is R so it should convert R into 0 and print it out

Comment: oh. That's right. I realize it now. Thanks so much

Comment: It displays 48 because that is the ASCII decimal value of the character 0. `0` is an integer, `'0'` is a character.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in our method `convertColourToNum`

```
if (colour == 'R')
        index = '0';
    else if (colour == 'Y')
        index = '1';
    else if (colour == 'G')
        index = '2';
    else 
        index = '3';
```

Notice how you used `''` around the numbers. This makes java think that you have a `char`, so it is actually returning the ASCII value for 0 and storing it in `index`. What you should be doing instead is

```
if (colour == 'R')
        index = 0;
    else if (colour == 'Y')
        index = 1;
    else if (colour == 'G')
        index = 2;
    else 
        index = 3;
```

That way, java realizes that you want the `int` data type, and will store an `int` in `index`.